# Canvas App (or equivalent) for Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning, canvas, lightning-web-components, canvas-app

We are currently using the [force:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:canvasApp/documentation) lightning component to embed an external site securely into Salesforce.

[The Spring '19 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_lwc.htm) is introducing [Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/introducing-lightning-web-components.html) as the future of Lightning development for Salesforce.  If we wanted to convert our existing `force:canvasApp` component into the new LWC Model, what are my options?  Is there a different way altogether to embed external sites securely into Salesforce with the new LWC Model?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aura Components are not going to be deprecated any time soon . I raised this question on the twitter to the PM for canvas and LWC and here is the response from him , please check screenshot below

[image]

Hence for few more releases I think you will have to use the force:canvasapp and the aura bundle .

Comment: +1 Exactly what I suspected, but I didn't comment because I didn't know enough about it. I actually even estimated 2 releases, though of course, I can't prove it, lol.

Comment: It's been two releases :-P  Anyway to check for an update on this?

Comment: I think it's been many more than 2 releases, would love to see this functionality soon, ideally with two way communication between lwc component and canvas app

Comment: @ScottMorrison Reaching to PM via Twitter would be helpful. I will also follow up internally.

Comment: any update on this @MohithShrivastava?

Comment: @Wookie88 Feb 2022, no luck yet?

Comment: Apparently not...

Comment: Hi Mo, can you please update your answer so it clearly reflects whether canvas support will ever come to LWCs or whether this is now considered a legacy technology by Salesforce.